# How to disable vertical bounce in SwiftUI on a single ScrollView

Tags: modal-dialog, swiftui, scrollview, bounce

I have a half modal view coming from the bottom of the screen with a scrollView, and when there's isn't enough content to scroll I want the drag gesture on the internal scrollView to apply to the modal and expand it or collapse it.
I tried using:

```
init() {
   UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
}
```

And it works fine but this disables the bouncing effect on all the scrollViews in my app.
Is there a way to apply this for a single ScrollView or at least a single View?

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to a ViewModifier:

```
struct SomeModifier: ViewModifier {
    init() {
      UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content
    }
}

ScrollView {
  Text("Some scroll view")
}.modifier(SomeModifier()
```

Comment: This has the same effect, all my ScrollViews in the app stopped bouncing

Comment: hmm how about trying the swift introspect library, https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect. you can use it like this:

```
      ScrollView {
        Text("yo")
      }.introspectScrollView { scrollView in
        scrollView.bounces = false
      }
```